# Uncought TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i am reading my props which are passed into my component i am getting this error. (Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.) Possibly i am doing some mistake in destructuring my props.

```
const YourRequests = () => {
    const send = (book_id, msg) => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' + book_id + '/' + msg + '/addchat/').then(response => response.json()).then(result => console.log(result)).then(
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/your_sended_request/')
                .then(data => data.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setBook({ Yourbooks: data })
                }).catch(err => console.log(err)))
            }

    const [book, setBook] = useContext(RequestContext)
    console.log(book.Yourbooks)
    return(
        book.Yourbooks.map(book => 
                <div className='your_books' key={book.request_book_details.book_id}>
                    <div className='bookcont'>
                        <div className='bookimg'>
                            <img src={book.request_book_details.book_img} className='boimg'></img>
                        </div>
                        <div className='bookdet'>
                            <span className='bookname'>{book.request_book_details.book_name}</span>
                            <span className='book_added_data'>{book.request_book_details.time}</span>
                        </div>
                        <button className='delete'>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <div className='comment'>
                        <div className='chat_container' id={book.request_book_details.book_id + '_container'}>
                            <div className='chat_msg'>
                                {console.log(book)}

                                <Chats bookdet={book}></Chats>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='text_send'><input type='text' className='msg' id={book.request_book_details.book_id}></input>
                            <input type='button' className='sendbutton' value='send' onClick={() => send(book.request_book_details.book_id, document.getElementById(book.request_book_details.book_id).value)}></input>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            className='show_hide_char' onClick={(e) => {
                                document.getElementById(book.request_book_details.book_id + '_container').style.height = document.getElementById(book.request_book_details.book_id + '_container').style.height != 'auto' ? 'auto' : '0px';
                                e.target.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML == 'Show Comment' ? 'Hide Comment' : 'Show Comment'
                            }}>Show Comment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>))}

   
     
export default YourRequests;
```

My chats.js file

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import { BookContext } from '../../../contexts/BookDetails'
import './chats.css'
const Chats = ({bookdet}) =>{
    const setstat = () =>{
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user_booklist/')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            setBook({ status: data.status })
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
const [book, setBook] = useContext(BookContext);
if(bookdet.request_details.accepted){
   setstat()
   return(Object.entries(book.status.chats).map(([key, value]) =>
    <div className='text'>
        <div className='time_user'>
            <div className='user'>{value[0]}</div>
            <div className='time'>{key.substring(11, 19)+' | '+key.substring(5, 10)}</div>
        </div>
        <p className='text_msg'>{value[1]}</p>
    </div >)
)}else{
    if(bookdet.reuqest_book_details.availibility){
        return(<p>Waiting to accept your request</p>)
    }
    else{
   return(<p>Book Has been Given to Someone Else</p>)
}

}
}
export default Chats;
```

[image: And the error in my console is this]

**Can someone help with this??**

Comment: The chats component is not getting anything as props. so when you try to destructure a undefined value, this error is thrown

Comment: <Chats bookdet={book}></Chats> but i have passed the prop

Comment: Its weird, even if you dont pass that prop, this error should not be thrown